# Chrome Macos - How to run command to restore window of specific user profile?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal

I have 3 user profiles running on Chrome at all times on separate desktops.

I want to make a command that restores the window (NOT opens a new window) a specific user profile window as It's slow to do so by clicking and holding the chrome icon in the dock. I've tried the following:
Opens a new window, not what I want!

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --profile-directory="Profile 3"`

**Maximises the existing Profile 3 window and makes a new tab for duckduckgo.com which is better, but still would like a way to not open a new tab, any way to do this?**

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome duckduckgo.com  --profile-directory="Profile 3"`

Once I figure this out I'll make 3 different desktop shortcuts as described here
[How to create dock icon for running terminal command in Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397647/how-to-create-dock-icon-for-running-terminal-command-in-mac-os)

Answer (score 0):

Create desktop icon for terminal command:

1. Create a plain text document in TextEdit

#!/bin/bash
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome duckduckgo.com  --profile-directory="Profile 3"

2. Save the file as fileName.command
3. Open Terminal and navigate to the directory which you saved the file
4. Type in chmod +x fileName.command and hit enter
5. Get info on file and drag icon image to icon to change
6. Rename .command to .app and drag to dock